# Sending a KEY to a Page with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

i need to simulate something like pressing F5 to trigger a refresh of a site.
the idea was using sendKeysAndWait ${KEY_12}, but as i understand it, i need an element as target for that command.

With Webdriver i solved the problem like this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(_driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.F12).perform();
```

Is there a way to send a F12 or any other Key to a Page?

I tried sending the event to the body, doesn't work.

I tried sending the event to the first input i find (this works but i dont want to do it, there are sites without any input elements in out appplication)

my last hope was a javascript file.
i created a function and added it to the Selenium Core extensions :

```
Selenium.prototype.doHotkey = function(target,value) {
var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";
keyboardEvent[initMethod](
               "keypress", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
                true, // bubbles
                true, // cancelable
                window, // viewArg: should be window
                false, // ctrlKeyArg
                false, // altKeyArg
                false, // shiftKeyArg
                false, // metaKeyArg
                value, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
                0 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
);
// window.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent); // does nothing 
// document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent); // does nothing
body.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent); // is undefined
}
```

But here i found, that window is not my Page at all. Any tips?

Comment: How do u want to do this, using selenium IDE ?

Comment: Well, my question is exactly that. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can do that by `refresh` command in Selenium IDE

Comment: I don't really need a refresh, that was just an example of how it should work. I need to send another key (F12), which triggers an event in the page, and think there is a javascript function listening to a KeyDown event, but the site is generated by a framework, and the functions, and elements have generic names, so i cant call the function itself. I just want to simulate pressing that key like a real person would.

Comment: http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2013/09/25/using-special-keys-in-selenium-ide-part-2/

Comment: Yup i read that and part 1 too. 
It is the reason, I assume that ${KEY_12} is the key i wanna send, and that i need a target for my command. 
Now i need help determining what that target could be, and IF there is a valid one.
I naively tried the body of the page, but that didn't work.

Comment: you just need to find an element that will trigger the event. You could always try <body> element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do it with an JS file and a Selenium Core extension (save the code in a JS file and add it to the extensions under options/general) then you can call it with

```
command : hotkey
target :
Value : 13 // for enter
```

JS:

```
Selenium.prototype.doHotkey = function(target,value) {

var win = this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow(); // this way you get your site
var doc = win.document;
var keyboardEvent = doc.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";


keyboardEvent[initMethod](
               "keydown", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
                true, // bubbles
                true, // cancelable
                win, // viewArg: should be window
                false, // ctrlKeyArg
                false, // altKeyArg
                false, // shiftKeyArg
                false, // metaKeyArg
                value, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
                0 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0

);

doc.body.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);

}
```